# Array Type Confusion?

Tags: java, arrays, types

This is my code for the class, ListOfLists. The constructor should make an array of type NameList.

```
public class ListOfLists {
private int capacity;
private NameList[] listOfLists;
private int size = 0;

public ListOfLists(int capacity) {
    listOfLists = new NameList[capacity];
}
```

My NameList class looks something like this..

```
public class NameList{
    public NameList(String initial){
    i = initial;
    }
    public void add(String data){
    ...
    }
```

If I make a new object in the Main of ListOfLists called k..

```
ListOfLists k = new ListOfLists(5);
```

How come I cannot do..

```
k.add("Whatever") ?
```

I get the error.. 
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ListOfLists

Comment: You are calling `add` on a reference of type `ListOfLists`. Does that type declare an `add` method?

Comment: Give us all the relevant code, we cannot see how the `add()` method is implemented or what is your `i` in the `NameList`

Comment: The add method belongs to NameList. You have two options, make a proxy add method inside ListOfLists, or extend NameList.

Comment: What you probably meant to do was `k.getNameList(i).add("Whatever");`.

Answer (score 1):

```
How come I cannot do..
```

because you don't have `add` method in `ListOfLists` class.

If you want to use `add` method of class `NameList` then get the value of `listOfLists` which is of type `NameList` and then add the `Whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

`k` which is of type `ListOfLists` is something you wrote yourself, and doesn't extend anything. If you didn't write an `add` method, you can't call it. If you want a list that also has other properties, try extending `ArrayList` in your `ListOfLists` class.